# Parsing HTML string from API in React-Native?

Tags: html, react-native

What is the best way to parse an API response from HTML into react native?

An example of a string I get back from the API is:

<`>
"description_html": "<p>This warm and welcoming home offers six sizable bedrooms and three full bathrooms. Step inside to a beautiful interior, featuring hardwood flooring and elegant chandeliers. You&#39;ll love cooking in the open concept kitchen that&#39;s equipped with stainless steel appliances and tons of storage space. There&#39;s the added convenience of in-unit laundry. Even better, enjoy a lush backyard, providing a calm hideaway where you can relax and decompress after a busy day. Parking spaces available on a first come first serve basis.</p><p>This home boasts an ideal location in Rainier Valley. It&#39;s a short walk to Safeway for groceries and Walgreens is a quick drive down the road for other necessities. There are plenty of dining options in the area including Cafe Ibex, Pho Bac, and Emerald City Fish &amp; Chips. Spend the afternoon outdoors at Mt. Baker Beach or York Park. It&#39;s only a few miles from downtown where you&#39;ll find Pier 55 and the Seattle Aquarium. Getting there is also easy with access to the I-5 and the Light Rail nearby.</p>"
</`>

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a third-party package is probably your best option. I've used this one in the past: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html and it worked well.